# Split Footer Content Into Left and Right

Tags: html, css

```
<footer>
<div class="copyrights">
<p>&copy 2015. <a style="color: #fff;" href="index.html">Free Xbox Live Gold Membership and Free Xbox Live Gold Codes</a>. All rights reserved.<a href="contact.html">Contact Us!</a><a href="tos.html">ToS</a></p></div>
</div>
```

I have this footer code and right now I want the copyright to be on the left and then the Contact and TOS to be on the right aligned. However I have hard time just aligning the content to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer>
    <div class="copyrights" style="overflow: hidden;">
        <p style="float: left;">&copy 2015. <a style="color: #fff;" href="index.html">Free Xbox Live Gold Membership and Free Xbox Live Gold Codes</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
        <p style="float: right;"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us!</a> <a href="tos.html">ToS</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suggest you to place the stylesheet in an external file and target the elements with class names. Inline style is not easy to maintain.